# qt QLineEdit from designer not responding to textChanged

Tags: python, qt, designer

I created a GUI with qt designer (PySide6) with a `QLineEdit` object 'lineEdit_r0' that for debugging purposes should just print something. For some reason, the `textChanged` signal is emitted only when the frame is initialized, but not when it is changed. I also have a working code example, but I cannot see the difference, besides that the example creates the window manually and not with the designer.

**my code:**

```
class FrmMain(QMainWindow, Ui_Hauptfenster):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.show()
        self.menu_Trap_Information.triggered.connect(self.open_trap_information)

    def open_trap_information(self):
        frm_trap_information.show()


class FrmTrapInformation(QMainWindow, Ui_Trap_Information):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.lineEdit_r0.textChanged[str].connect(self.update_trap_information_electrodes())

    def update_trap_information_electrodes(self):
        print("test")

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
frm_main = FrmMain()
frm_trap_information = FrmTrapInformation()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

**working example:**

```
class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        hbox = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.lbl = QLabel(self)
        qle = QLineEdit(self)

        qle.textChanged[str].connect(self.onChanged)

        hbox.addWidget(self.lbl)
        hbox.addSpacing(20)
        hbox.addWidget(qle)

        self.resize(250, 200)
        self.setWindowTitle('QLineEdit')
        self.show()

    def onChanged(self, text):
        print("something changed!")
        self.lbl.setText(text)
        self.lbl.adjustSize()


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
ex = Example()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: To me it seems that I cannot pass any parameters to the method that is passed with 'connect'. If I leave 'self.lineEdit_r0.textChanged[str].connect(self.update_trap_information_electrodes)' completely empty it works. IS there a way to pass information to the method?

Comment: What are you using PySide2/6 pyqt5/6?

Comment: I am using PySide6

Comment: `self.lineEdit_r0.textChanged[str].connect(self.update_trap_information_electrodes())` You called the funciton there. Drop the parenthesize.

Comment: Yes that works, but is there a way to pass additional information to the method that is triggered here?

Comment: `lambda: self.update_trap_information_electrodes(whatever)`

Comment: But then it seems that the actual change in the textfield is replaced by `whatever`. This is for the case that I want to print the input and not simply "test".

Comment: Try `lambda text_from_le: self.update_trap_information_electrodes(text_from_le, whatever)`. See [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlineedit.html#textChanged). and read about lambda in Python

Comment: Thank you, that is perfect! Indeed I have to recheck the lambda function.

Comment: Have you solved it?

Comment: yes, the main mistake were the parentheses that shouldn't be there when a method is passed to the connect: `connect(self.update_trap_information_electrodes)´. The lambda function then is very important when you want to pass arguments with the signal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main mistake was that the method that is passed to the `connect` must not contain parentheses. It has to be:

```
self.lineEdit_r0.textChanged[str].connect(self.update_trap_information_electrodes)
```

With the lambda function and passing additional arguments it can be e.g.:

```
self.lineEdit_r0.textChanged[str].connect(lambda text: self.update_trap_information_electrodes(text, "r0"))
```

In this case `text` would be the value that is entered in the QLineedit and "r0" the additional argument.